# What is the best way to create a HDF5 dataset from timestamp-image-pairs?

Tags: arrays, c, file, append, hdf5

I have to create HDF5 files from images that come with a timestamp in C. I do NOT know in advance how many of these pairs I will be getting, so a fixed-size dataset is not an option.

A sample of my data comes as a large (~ 12 x 10^6) array of uint8_t containing a flattened version of the image in addition to a uint64_t timestamp. I have added C equivalents of my solutions for better understanding.

I could think of 2 possible solutions for this, but I have my problems with both. I would appreciate some pointers here:

**VERSION 1**

I create a 2-D uint8_t dataset with an initial size of 0. On the go, I extend the dataset during each iteration and write the image data to the HDF5 file. Here, I planned on putting the timestamps in a corresponding uint64_t array in the dataset attributes. The problem is that I found no way to extend an attribute array on the go, so I would have to save all timestamps in a temporary array and add it to the attributes later. Not only is this memory-consuming but also in case of a crash, I am left with images but without the timestamps.

```
uint8_t images[][IMG_BUF_SIZE];

(as attribute:)
uint64_t timestamps[];
```

**VERSION 2**

I tried to use compound data types so that I would have a 1-D array of samples of the compound type. Every sample would contain the uint64_t timestamp and the large uint8_t array. The problem I have with this is that I read in the docs of the HDF5 that within compound data types, it is not advisable to have "large arrays".

```
typedef struct 
{
    uint64_t timestamp;
    uint8_t payload[IMG_BUF_SIZE];
} time_image_t;

time_image_t array[];
```

How can this be done? Datasets of these types should be pretty common, but I was unable to find a standard way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: I advise reading the "Special Issues" section in the Attributes chapter of the  **HDF5 User's Guide**. It says: _"We consider the maximum size of an attribute to be 64K bytes"_. So, if your timestmap array is <64K, you will be OK. If not, there are two ways to store attributes >64K bytes: 1) in dense attribute storage, or 2) in a separate dataset. There are examples of both techniques in the Users's Guide. See pgs 306-308 in the Guide for Release 1.10.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this use-case is through the usage of an HDF5 compound dataset (containing two members: `timestamp` and `payload`), just like described in version 2 above.

Additionally, the dataset will have to be extendable so that it can grow according to the size of data that you will get (which is unknown before hand). To avoid overwriting already stored data in the dataset, you'll need to work with selections (hyperslab or point) when writing data into it.

One way to solve your use-case could be through the usage of [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com) in C as follows (note that in this example, I just add two "rows" to the dataset - you could have a loop adding as many "rows" as needed to solve what you have in mind):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "HDFql.h"

#define IMG_BUF_SIZE 3

typedef struct
{
    uint64_t timestamp;
    uint8_t payload[IMG_BUF_SIZE];
}time_image_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // declare variables
    char script[1024];
    time_image_t data;

    // create HDF5 file named 'data.h5' and use (i.e. open) it
    hdfql_execute("create and use file data.h5");

    // prepare script to create an extendable dataset named 'dset' of data type compound (containing two members named 'timestamp' and 'payload')
    sprintf(script, "create dataset dset as compound(timestamp as unsigned bigint offset %d, payload as unsigned tinyint(%d) offset %d)(unlimited) size %d", offsetof(time_image_t, timestamp), IMG_BUF_SIZE, offsetof(time_image_t, payload), sizeof(time_image_t));

    // execute script
    hdfql_execute(script);

    // register variable 'data' for subsequent usage (by HDFql)
    hdfql_variable_register(&data);

    // populate variable 'data' with some values
    data.timestamp = 123;
    data.payload[0] = 10;
    data.payload[1] = 20;
    data.payload[2] = 30;

    // insert data into last row of dataset 'dset' thanks to a point selection
    hdfql_execute("insert into dset[-1] values from memory 0");

    // populate variable 'data' with more values
    data.timestamp = 456;
    data.payload[0] = 75;
    data.payload[1] = 85;
    data.payload[2] = 95;

    // alter (i.e. change) dimension of dataset 'dset' to +1
    hdfql_execute("alter dimension dset to +1");

    // insert data into last row of dataset 'dset' thanks to a point selection
    hdfql_execute("insert into dset[-1] values from memory 0");

    // unregister variable 'data' as it is no longer used (by HDFql)
    hdfql_variable_unregister(&data);

    // close HDF5 file 'data.h5'
    hdfql_execute("close file");

    return 0;

}
```